# add template to WHMCS

Tags: php, cpanel, whmcs

I download [This][1] template  and I added a template to `(public_html/My_Host/templates)` and change the Template from admin panel `(Setup->General Settings->Template)` but it does not work just six template work
I download the template from

```
[1]: https://colorlib.com/preview/theme/hostspace/
  [2]: https://colorlib.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you downloaded WHMCS Templates ?   (Note:Normal html5 templates never work as whmcs template ).

If yes, you need to upload and extract in "public_html/WHMCS_DIRECTORY/templates" .

Then it will list out in WHMCS "Setup->General Settings->Template" area.

Comment: Thanks, Ebin can you give me free templates for WHMCS

Comment: we at https://www.ucartz.com/ using custom whmcs templates (we build that ourself ) .  Either you can hire any Devoloper or try to search on http://codecanyon.net for whmcs templates